# Bad Practice to use Nullable<T> with Value Types?

Tags: c#

Does maintenance become a nightmare on code that allows a nullable type of a value type?  I realize that `int?` is the equivalent of `Nullable<int>`, but my question is more geared towards the usability of it.  We see value types and naturally overlook them as not allowing `null`.  But bringing in the `Nullable<T>` with a shorthand of the question mark, it's obvious what it does but not always noticeable.

Is this one of those features that just because you *can* do it, doesn't mean you *should*?

What should be the preference?  A default value of a value type (i.e. `int SomeConfigOption = -1;`) or utilizing `Nullable<T>` (i.e. `int? SomeConfigOption;`)?

Comment: `Nullable<T>` is *only* meant to be used with value types. You seem to be asking if `Nullable<T>` should in general be considered harmful.

Comment: @Cameron I guess my wording was a little fuzzy.  And not necessarily directly harmful, just adding complexity.

Comment: Whatever you do, don't write a struct and then use `Nullable<T>` with it. I came across that in production code the other day, complete with passing it around by reference (as it was mutable). Just make it a class!

Comment: @TrueWill: I thought that was the question, but I not so sure. Yeah, NEVER do that!

Comment: @Truewill, unless there are other reasons to have it as a struct (we have some memory allocation routines that require value types)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> What should be the preference? A default value of a value type (i.e.
>   int SomeConfigOption = -1;) or utilizing Nullable (i.e. int?
>   SomeConfigOption;)?

In this case clearly you want `Nullable<T>` whenever you have the case that you have to account for ***the absence*** of a value. Magic numbers like -1 are a far worse maintenance nightmare.

This is a core feature of the C# language, as with other features it can be abused but it provides clear benefits as well - these benefits far outweigh any problems someone not proficient in the language might have reading the source code - time to get up to speed.

Comment: Ok, I like that answer.  But why is it that the framework itself doesn't utilize this?  For instance, `SelectedIndex` on a control often times has a value of `-1` when there is no selected item.  Why wouldn't MSFT want to utilize `Nullable<int>` for that??  That throws a wrench in my engine.

Comment: Because Nullable wasn't available until .NET 2.0

Comment: @HansPassant So preservation for the sake of tradition?

Comment: @Shark: breaking changes are always tough to make (and this change would have broken many existing apps) and if history is any guidance then Microsoft has always tried to painfully avoid it whenever it can.

Comment: @BrokenGlass Excellent.  Thank you for giving me a bit more insight today on this question.  Much appreciated, BrokenGlass.  I will take what you say and put it to good practice.

Comment: @Shark: `Nullable<T>` is useful in cases where all values of type `T` might be legitimately returned by a function or property, even if one didn't expect them.  For example, a function `int GetSubscribersAge(subscriberID)` might not be expected to return a negative number if a subscriber exists, but if a subscriber's age somehow gets reported a negative number (because it's stored wrong, or the computer's clock gets glitched to a date before the subscriber was born) code which regards a negative number as a "does not exist" indication could get very confused.  By contrast...

Comment: ...methods like `IndexOf` or properties like `SelectedIndex` cannot return or hold meaningful negative values except in the cases such values are explicitly defined to represent.

Comment: Am I the only one who sees that the "Don't use magic values in your code, use nullable" argument is bullshit? Null is as much a magic value as -1 or string.Empty!

Answer (score 3):

I think Nullable looks nice: code with Nullable types is quite self-documented.

Examples:

```
int? someConfigOption;
if (someConfigOption.HasValue)
{
    // Use someConfigOption.Value property.
}
else
{
    // Value is absent.
}
```

Another handy approach:

```
int value = someConfigOption.GetValueOrDefault();
```

Of course, the methods which take Nullable values as their parameters should be **well documented**.

Answer (score 0):

I much prefer a nullable type to a value type with a default value (which the developer then means null).  I have found more issues in code where default values are used to mean nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types should be used when "null" is a valid value. If null is a valid value, then using nullable types is a good practice. But if nullable values are not valid, then carrying the null value is bad practice.

Suppose a function GetClientID where the function reads from the DB, and returns a ClientID. Let's assume that GetClientID should never return NULL or empty.

While reading the value from the DB, a nullable type is the best practice for handling possible nulls from the DB. GetClientID therefore should use the nullable type to handle correctly the exception situation (failing / logging / etc) and making sure only valid values return.

The worst practice would be to return a nullable type. You can potentially be carrying an already invalid value that would be read somewhere in your code, failing far from where the invalid value was loaded (and becoming a maintenance nightmare).

So ask yourself, if the null value a valid value (valid is no the same as possible) and code accordingly.